# Create and run migrations in run time with Knex

Tags: javascript, knex.js, strapi

I'm using strapi alongside knex, however strapi doesn't create any migrations and when you edit a content type (Model) by deleting a property or renaming it, it doesn't delete the targeted property, it just creates a new one, and when you delete a model it doesn't actually delete the table on the database. 
This is really annoying because you'll end up with a lot of redundancies and unused tables and fields while developing.

What I'm doing is overriding the Strapi controllers that are responsible for creating, removing or updating a model and I want to be able to create a migration with the new schema on those controllers and then run it so I keep my database clean and up-to-date with strapi's models.

I know about the existence of `knex.migrate.make` however it doesn't seem to address my issue and the docs don't really tell you how to provide the migration fields to that function.

I was able to also find this http://knexjs.org/#custom-migration-sources however once again the docs are not very clear on what options I can provide and how to solve my issue.

Ideally I would want to end up with something like:

```js
updateModel({attributes, table}){

  const updatedSchena = attributes
  knex.migrate.make(`update_${table.name}_table`, updatedSchema);
}
```

Edit:

I was able to create the new migration at run time but the contents of the file remain empty.

This is what I have so far

New [custom-migration-sources](http://knexjs.org/#custom-migration-sources) as indicated in the docs:

```js
class MyMigrationSource {
  // Must return a Promise containing a list of migrations.
  // Migrations can be whatever you want, they will be passed as
  // arguments to getMigrationName and getMigration
  constructor(name, attributes) {
    this.name = name
    this.attributes = attributes
    console.log('attributes: ', attributes)
  }
  getMigrations() {
    // In this example we are just returning migration names
    return Promise.resolve(['migration1'])
  }

  getMigrationName(migration) {
    return migration;
  }

  getMigration() {
    return {
      up(knex) {
        //const migrate = require('widget-knex-schema')
        return migrate.createTable(knex, this.name, this.attributes)
      },
      down(knex) {
        return knex.schema.dropTableIfExists(this.name)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Instantiate the new migration source

```js
const migration = new MyMigrationSource(modelJSON.collectionName, formatedAttributes)
```

Create the new migration with the custom configuration:

```js
  knex.migrate.make(`update_${name}_table`, {
     migrationSource: migration
   })
```

And the result is a new migration with these contents:

```js
exports.up = function(knex) {

};

exports.down = function(knex) {

};
```

NOTE: I know that  ´widget-knex-schema´is working because I use for other manually created migrations.

Can anyone link to any working examples or solutions on how to create migrations in run time?